# Loading animations through plist files in Cocos2dx

Tags: c++, animation, sprite, cocos2d-x

I'm learning to use `cocos2dx` these days.
Since now I've been able to load and play sprite animations saved as `.plist` files.
I'm loading animation this way:

```
CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("oras.plist");
CCAnimation *bearWalkingAnimation = CCAnimation::create();

for (int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; ++i )
{

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "bear" << i + 1  << ".png";

    std::string name = ss.str();
    CCSpriteFrame* sprite =  CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()>spriteFrameByName(name.c_str());
    bearWalkingAnimation->addSpriteFrame(sprite);

}
```

I rely on the fact that I know the images names, but now I'm trying to organize a little bit my code.

I was wondering if there is anyway of knowing at which plist file appertain sprite frames while loaded. Can I do that?How?

In other words I want to write a generic class able to load an animation only knowing `plist` file name. Something like:

```
void MyLoaderClass::LoadAnimation(std::string plist_file_name){ ....}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved building a `CCDictionary` from the loaded `plist` file:

```
CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile(fileName.c_str());

mAnimation = CCAnimation::create();

CCFileUtils *fileUtils = CCFileUtils::sharedFileUtils();
const char *fullPath = fileUtils->fullPathFromRelativePath(fileName.c_str());


CCDictionary *dictionary = CCDictionary::createWithContentsOfFileThreadSafe(fullPath);
CCDictionary *framesDict = static_cast<CCDictionary*> (dictionary->objectForKey("frames"));

CCArray *keys = framesDict->allKeys();

for (int i = 0 ; i < keys->count(); ++i)
{
    CCString *spriteFileName = static_cast<CCString *> (keys->objectAtIndex(i));
    CCSpriteFrame* sprite =  CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName(spriteFileName->getCString());
    mAnimation->addSpriteFrame(sprite);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

//"horse.png" through which batch node crate

```
CCSpriteBatchNode* spritebatch = CCSpriteBatchNode::create("horse.png");
CCSpriteFrameCache* cache = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache();
cache->addSpriteFramesWithFile("horse.plist");

// "hero" is CCSprite and "horse_1.png" is a sprite in "horse.png" batch node

hero = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("horse_1.png");

addChild(spritebatch);
spritebatch->addChild(hero);

CCLog("In the anim2");

CCArray* animFrames = CCArray::createWithCapacity(16);
char str[100] = {0};
for(int i = 1; i < 16; i++)
{
    // in my batch node all the sprite name as 'horse_1.png', 'horse_2.png'.....
    sprintf(str, "horse_%i.png", i);
    CCSpriteFrame* frame = cache->spriteFrameByName( str );
    animFrames->addObject(frame);
}
CCAnimation* animation = CCAnimation::createWithSpriteFrames(animFrames, .1f);
animation->setRestoreOriginalFrame(true);
hero->runAction( CCRepeatForever::create( CCAnimate::create(animation) ) );
```